# Computed property other file

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

Using Vue.js. Will a computed property work properly if it's based on an external file variable? So for example:

```js
import vars from "./vars.js
return default {
    computed: {
        booleano : function() {
            if (vars.variab == 0){
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

vars.js

```js
var variab = 0

change = function(){
    variab = 1
}

return default {variab}
```

If `change` is called, and vars.var is changed in the vars.js file, will it also impact booleano?

If not what is the correct way to do this example?

Answer (score 0):

You would need the variable to be converted by Vue into a reactive variable. You can do that by using the object as the `data` initializer of your Vue instance.

```js
const vars = {
  variab: 0
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      vars
    };
  },
  computed: {
    booleano() {
      if (this.vars.variab == 0) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  vars.variab = 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="booleano">Yes</div>
  <div v-else>No</div>
</div>
```